# IF in a Regex expresion? (replace something in file names ONLY if file type is xxx)

Tags: regex, pcre

Ok, I know some regex but this fooling me...

I usually manage every month hundreds of files submited and have to make some checks and replaces before making them available again in our intranet...

I'm doing it locally on hd on Windows, through a file renamer program which can do pcre but only do one line at a time, so all should be in the same regex.

The problem is that I would like to do replacements only if file type is xxx.

For example, replace all spaces for underscores ONLY if extension is jpg|jpeg|jpe

so

> this is a test.jpg => this_is_a_test.jpg
>
> this is a another test.jpe => this_is_a_another_test.jpe
>
> this is a test.docx => this is a test.docx

Jpg is an EXAMPLE, I do diferent replaces for each extension and not for all extensions, so something which replaces spaces in the above example in the .docx will be wrong...

is it posible???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find spaces, and then look ahead to see the extension:

```
 (?=.*\.jp(?:g|e)$)
```

Note the leading space.

Try it here: https://regex101.com/r/ZgDv7S/1

Answer (score 0):

You said you were on Windows, but do you have WSL (Bash for Linux) or something similar available? If so, here is a quick way to do this from the Linux command line:

```
rename 's/ /_/g;' *.jpg *.jpe
```

Explanation: `rename` runs the given Perl script on the name of the specified files.